# What is the origin/etymology of the expression "come-hither"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions

As in "She gave him a "come-hither" look.

I found nothing except the date of first use (1925), which has no source.

Comment: Seems like a straightforward description which has ossified into a set phrase through persistent usage. Nothing particularly mysterious about it. I would be interested in seeing the examples of early use when it was already past the "simple descriptive" phase and transitioning into idiom. Or perhaps there was a single, exceptional use which popularized it.

Comment: The "etymology" is merely employing the direct address *Come hither* as an adnominal to describe the look as one which "speaks" the invitation. It's very common; Google will show you *a go away look*, *a help me look*, *an I've got this look*, and (going back to the 19th century) *a goodbye look*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The noun, 'come-hither', derives from the verbal phrase, 'come hither'. The first attestation as a noun shown in *OED Online* is from 1900:

> **come-hither**, *n.*
>   *colloq.*
>     An invitation to approach, so *fig.* enticement. Chiefly in attrib. use, with *look, eye,* etc. Also as *adv.* (Cf. comether *n.*)
>
> 1900 *Daily News* 10 July 6/2   It's no' the money, and it's no' the looks. It's jist the come hither in the eye.

["come-hither, n.". *OED Online.* September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/36850?rskey=ziZqlA&result=2&isAdvanced=false (accessed September 14, 2016).]

Much earlier attestation is readily found with contemporary popular news archive searches, wherein the noun is often used with 'put':

[image: comehither1]

([*The Moreton Bay Courier*, Brisbane, Qld., Wed 3 Aug 1859.](http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/3721697?searchTerm=come-hither))

In these uses the derivation from the verbal phrase is quite evident.

The noun form cross-referenced in *OED Online*, 'comether', represents a dialectal pronunciation of 'come-hither':

> **comether**, *n.*
>   **Etymology:** A dialect pronunciation of *come hither*, used as a coaxing invitation to cows, horses, etc.
>   *dial.* or *colloq.*
>
> In **to put one's (the) comether on**: to exercise persuasion or coaxing on, to persuade over, coax, wheedle; to get under one's influence.
>
> 1838   S. Lover *Handy Andy* ii. 22   He..looks pistols at any one that attempts putting his comether on the widow.

["comether, n.". *OED Online.* September 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/36878 (accessed September 14, 2016).]

An earlier attestation for 'comether' than that given by *OED Online* is also available through the aforementioned news archive searches:

[image: comether1]

([*The Sydney Gazette and New South Wales Advertiser*, Tue 29 Dec 1835.](http://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/2201934?searchTerm=comether))

Further investigation with specialized dialect resources may reveal regional sources (from the evidence shown, Ireland) as well as earlier attestations.