# What is the term for phrases that are compound adjectives, similar to "come-hither look", "high-school-teaching voice"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology, compound-adjectives

I know the [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/348475/15661), and although it's listed as a noun, [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come-hither) tells me the definition, but I want to know the name of this *sort* of adjective.

Wiktionary has it grouped as [English Exocentric compound phrases](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_exocentric_verb-noun_compounds), but that's quite what I'm looking for.

Another example is the title of this book: [Don't Make Me Use My High School Teacher Voice](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-School-Teacher-Voice/dp/1724243543), or the term ['Big-Boy pants'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/big-boy_pants#English), like "Time to put on your 'big boy' pants."

Rather than use a straightforward adjective like "Seductive look" or "Annoyed" they use [circumlocutionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circumlocutionary) language evoke a more complicated and particular situation, circumstance or role.

But is there a specific term for this type of adjective?

Comment: Not technical, but to me they're imagery. The rule in film and writing is *show, don't tell*. It's more dynamic to describe a face (come-hither) than to label it seductive.

Comment: @YosefBaskin that describes, but I don't think that's actual terminology.

Comment: Those examples show different things. "high-school teaching voice" is better English. Using "teach" there just sounds ignorant.

Comment: But @Lambie, "high-school teaching voice" misses the entire point of the phrase.

Comment: high-school-teach voice is pretty meaningless to me. I think you need the ing there.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not sure where you're getting just "high-school-teach" from or how you're missing the "-er" at the end that makes it "high-school-teacher"...?

Comment: Originally, you had it in the title. That's where....OK for: high-school-teacher voice

Comment: @Lambie ahhh sorry I didn't realise I made the initial typo or that somebody fixed it for me. Apologies!

Comment: @AncientSwordRage No worries. By the way, I had answered this question, it only got one vote, then the question was asked again, and everybody again agreed with what I consider to be slightly inaccurate. Some are adjectives that are compound, others are full-on sentences. I call the latter extended adjectives, based on an article I found on them. :)